# BigQuery client does not recognize dates on query

Tags: python, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to run queries to BigQuery using the Python SDK. This is my code:

```
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """
SELECT 
    SUM(Success) AS Success,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(Success)/COUNT(*) as KPI
FROM `dpto-bigdata.bbva.altas`
WHERE
    Date >= DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    and Date <= current_date()
    """
    df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()
```

This works without any problem. However, I have found out that if I use the SQL function `current_date()` I am loosing the partitioning functionality my table has, so I have changed the code to the following one:

```
    client = bigquery.Client()
    today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    query = """
SELECT 
    SUM(Success) AS Success,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(Success)/COUNT(*) as KPI
FROM `dpto-bigdata.bbva.altas`
WHERE
    Date >= DATE_SUB({0}, INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    and Date <= {0}
    """.format(today)
    df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()
```

With this, I am calculating the current date on my Python code and passing it to the query explicitly, but I am getting the following error:

> BadRequest: 400 No matching signature for function DATE_SUB for argument types: INT64, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signatures: DATE_SUB(DATE, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_SUB(DATETIME, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART); DATE_SUB(TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL INT64 DATE_TIME_PART) at [8:19]

It seems as if the `today` variable is being received as an INT64 type instead of the string it is. I have tried using `DATE_SUB(DATE({0}), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`, but I then receive the same error but for the SQL function `DATE()`, which is the first one on being executed.

I have performed some verifications:

```
print(today)
2021-06-16

print(type(today))
<class 'str'>

print(query)
SELECT 
    SUM(Success) AS Success,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(Success)/COUNT(*) as KPI
FROM `dpto-bigdata.bbva.altas`
WHERE
    Date >= DATE_SUB(2021-06-16, INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    and Date <= 2021-06-16
```

I am executing the code on a Cloud Run instance. Anyone knows what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. The problem was that although `today` var was a string, when I was inserting it to the query it was considered as an INT64 since it started by a number. The solution was declaring it as a string adding the following change:

```
    query = """
SELECT 
    SUM(Success) AS Success,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    SUM(Success)/COUNT(*) as KPI
FROM `dpto-bigdata.bbva.altas`
WHERE
    Date >= DATE_SUB("{0}", INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
    and Date <= "{0}"
    """.format(today)
```

Notice that now I am using `DATE_SUB("{0}", INTERVAL 30 DAY)` instead of `DATE_SUB({0}, INTERVAL 30 DAY)`.